# Wordpress - Better to create pages using php script OR one page which is dynamic?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a large mysql table with a list of items with names, locations etc (separate to my wordpress table). 
I want to create wordpress pages for each item and i'm just wondering would it be better to:

- use a wordpress custom page template and get the data dynamically
  using php  or
- use a php script to loop through each item and create an individual page using the wordpress api?

Which would be better in terms of being indexed by Google?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Which would be better in terms of being indexed by Google?" — How do you expect Google to tell the difference? It makes an HTTP request. It gets a response. How that response is generated is transparent.

Comment: As I see it , there's no difference between those 2 approaches for Google. Do what's comfortable and logically right to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are working under wordpress, then you should always go for wordpress api, as it is easy to use, as well as gives you lot of flexibility and predefined functions to fetch and give a proper layout to data.

I hope you got my point.